# Connect Cordova 9 mobile app to Java Web Service using Ajax call

Tags: java, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am very new to Cordova, I have installed Cordova version 9 which I am developing on android studio.
I have a simple ajax call to my web service layer which is written in Java. For some reason I am not able to connect to my web service from my mobile app, it returns 404 status. The same url is connected from emulator's browser but not from the application developed. I have white-listed my url in config.xml. Below is the config.xml and ajax code.

Config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <preferance name="android-usesCleartextTraffic" value="true" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
    <access origin="http://192.168.0.111:8091" subdomains="true"/>
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.111:8091/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://192.168.0.111:8091/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">        
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Ajax code:

```
document.getElementById("btnLogin").addEventListener("click", onClickOfLogin);
    function onClickOfLogin(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "http://192.168.0.111:8091/ZeOMSWS/AppLogin",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(resultObj) {
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Registration request has been sent for HR approval. You will receive an email once approved and then you can proceed with Login.', 
                    onSuccessDismissOfAlert, 
                    'Info', 
                    'OK');
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                console.log("Error status " + status);
                console.log("Error request status text: " + request.statusText);
                console.log("Error request status: " + request.status);
                console.log("Error request response text: " + request.responseText);
                console.log("Error response header: " + request.getAllResponseHeaders());
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Error Occured.' + error, 
                    onErrorDismissOfAlert, 
                    'Info', 
                    'OK');
            }
        });
    }
```

As I mentioned earlier I am using Cordova 9 with SDK version 29 and emulator is on Android 10.
I have been stuck with this for more than 2 days. I have tried so many solutions on google, I yet don't understand where I am going wrong. Please help me know what is that I am missing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in Android SDK version 29 permit ajax calls to https services by default.

**HTTP requests cannot be sent.**

Simply change the URLs in your app and server responses from http:// to https://

Otherwise:

1. add widget in *config.xml*:

```
    <widget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

2. edit platform android in *config.xml*:

```
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
```

Hope useful

[Protecting users with TLS by default in Android P](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html)[1](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html)

[Android高版本http网络请求失败的Cordova配置处理](https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/article/1414675)